# Stack Frame and Stack Pointer

Tags: assembly, gdb

```
(gdb) i r esp
esp 0xbffff7a0 0xbffff7a0
(gdb) x/32xw $esp
0xbffff7a0: 0x00000000 0x08049744 0xbffff7b8 0x080482d9
0xbffff7b0: 0xb7f9f729 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff7e8 0x00000000
0xbffff7c0: 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff880 0xbffff7e8 0xb7fd6ff4
0xbffff7d0: 0xb7ff47b0 0x08048510 0xbffff7e8 0x080484bb
0xbffff7e0: 0xbffff9b7 0x08048510 0xbffff848 0xb7eafebc
0xbffff7f0: 0x00000002 0xbffff874 0xbffff880 0xb8001898
0xbffff800: 0x00000000 0x00000001 0x00000001 0x00000000
0xbffff810: 0xb7fd6ff4 0xb8000ce0 0x00000000 0xbffff848
(gdb) p 0xbffff7e0 - 0xbffff7a0
$1 = 64
(gdb) x/s password_buffer
0xbffff7c0: "?o??\200????????o???G??\020\205\004\b?????\204\004\b????\020\205\004\bH???????\002"
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0xbffff7bc: 0x00000000
```

I want to know in details how do we know that 0xbffff7c0 (`password_buffer`) is located at 0xb7fd6ff4 (third row, second column) in the stack frame, and how do we know that 0xbffff7bc (`auth_flag`) is located at 0x00000000 (second row, fifth column) in the stack frame.
Where are the `password_buffer` and `auth_flag` values stored? Are they stored in the stack frame?

```
char password_buffer[16];  
int auth_flag = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are. Local variables are part of the [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of a function.

Regarding your statements on the stack in GDB:

The most-left column describes addresses, while the other ones hold values at these addresses (+ offset). So `password_buffer` isn't "located" at `0xb7fd6ff4` but it contains `0xf4` at index `0`, `0x6f` at index `1`, and so on (reversed because gdb displays values with little-endianess). Similarly, `auth_flag`'s value is `0x00000000`.